# Apply/Register conflicting plugins to different charts

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I have defined two slightly different Chart.js plugins and I have a page with two different charts. I want to apply the first plugin to the first chart and the second to the second chart.

According to the [source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/647dc582cd85fc8e25d49cf0e38d459c582b2652/src/core/core.plugin.js), there are a register and unregister function for plugins, but you register them to some global variable 'Chart.plugins'.

I have tried a solution like this:

```
Chart.plugins.register(plugin1);
window.myBar = new Chart(...);
Chart.plugins.unregister(plugin1);

Chart.plugins.register(plugin2);
window.myBar2 = new Chart(...);
Chart.plugins.unregister(plugin2);
```

but it appears this unregisters both plugins before anything happens. And if I do not unregister the plugins, the second overrides anything the first plugin does.

In addition it does not seem possible to register a plugin directly to a specific chart, as for example 'windows.myBar.plugins' is undefined.

Does anybody know if there exists a different solution?

Edit1: I thought of a possible workaround, namely by specifying the different behaviours of the plugins as options of the individual charts, and then define a single plugin that acts based on the specific options of a chart. But I would still like to know if there exists a way to apply plugins to a specific chart.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think a solution is to assign a specific property in your chart options for each plugin. Each chart will fill a different attribute to use each plugin. In your case, you have `plugin1` and `plugin2`.

Then, in each definition you will check for different attributes to see if that chart is using that plugin or not. For example, your definitions will be something like:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
  afterDraw: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.plugin_one_attribute) {
      // Plugin code here...  
    }
  }
});
```

To use this plugin, your chart will have to fill the plugin_one_attribute, in its options. Like this:

```
optionsUsingPlugin1 = {
  plugin_one_attribute: // Your variable to be used in the plugin goes here!
  responsive: true,      
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  title: {
    display: true
  } 
  // And any other config options you are already using
}
```

And use this when creating your chart:

```
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: optionsUsingPlugin1
});
```

So, in order to use plugin2, your myBar2 chart will need a specific attribute for plugin2 (which will check for it when registering). This way you can control which plugins will be active in each chart.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the best solution. I ended up making my plugin very modular and based on parameters specified in the options. But this solution solves the problem directly (and is more suitable for trying things out/prototyping!)

Comment: From [chartjs documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html), you can do: 
`var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    plugins: [{
        beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
            //..
        }
    }]
});`

Answer (score 4):

Currently Chartjs v2.9.4, from the [chartjs documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html), if you have multiple charts, each chart's plugin can be defined in the chart's config, like this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    plugins: [{ //plugin added for this chart
        beforeInit: function(chart, options) {
            //Add statements here
        }
   }],
   options: {
      responsive: true, // Instruct chartjs to respond nicely.
      maintainAspectRatio: false
   },
   // And any other config options as you wish
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is five years old. Nowadays, we can achieve this using `plugins` and hook calls in this case `beforeTooltipDraw` to capture the `tooltip.caretX`. Also we can use the build-in [interaction option](https://chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html) to achieve this.

This implementation works with versions 4.0.1 of [ChartJS](https://chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/)

```js
const plugin = {
  id: 'customText',
  afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
    const {ctx} = chart
    texts = options.texts

    if (!texts || texts.length === 0) return


    ctx.save();
    for (const text of texts) {
        const align =  text.align || 'center'
        const size = text.size || '20px'
        const family = text.font || 'Arial'
        const color = text.color || 'black'
        const str = text.str ?? null
        const x = text.x || 0
        const y = text.y || 0

        if (!str) continue

        ctx.textAlign = align
        ctx.font = `${size} ${family}`
        ctx.fillStyle = color
        ctx.fillText(str, x, y)
    }

    ctx.restore();
  }
}

const data = {
  labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
  }]
}

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      customText: {
        texts: [{
            x: 300,
            y: 50,
            str: 'Custom',
            size: '30px',
            font: 'Arial black'
          },
          {
            x: 300,
            y: 120,
            str: 'Text',
            color: 'red',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [plugin]
}

const $chart = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = new Chart($chart, config)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height:180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@4.0.1/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue (just register datalabels plugin LOCALLY)

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null`

ChartDataLabels plugin was registered globally in another chart that I had. instead I register locally and that fixed my issue. [Docs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)

basically I just had to remove this line in all my chart definitions

```
// Register the plugin to all charts:
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

instead I just need it the ChartDataLabels in my plugins object:

````
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels], ...```
````